# Journey goal based on non-contact record in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

We need to create a journey based on case records being created in Salesforce Service Cloud (Salesforce data event) where a certain case status is the trigger for the goal event (Cases are available as synchronized data source). As a given contact can have multiple cases at a time the entry mode needs to be "re-entry anytime".

**The issue:**
As the goal event doesn't allow attribute comparison between journey data and contact data we can't tie the goal event condition to the case record that triggered the journey. This results in the goal ejection of all contact instances currently in the journey, even those where the case status isn't correct, yet.

**The question**
Is there any way to tie the goal event to the record that triggered the journey without overly complex data modelling operations? Users without advanced SQL knowledge have to be able to "tweak" the journey.

**Simplified sample**

- Contact A 
  has
- Case 1
- Case 2

The creation of each case triggers a Journey entry to the same journey. Contact A is now 2 times in the same journey.

- Case 1 reaches Status "Closed"
- Case 2 does not reach status "Closed"

The journey goal is evaluated successful for Case 1

**Current outcome**
--> Both journey records (Contact A with Case 1, Contact A with Case 2) are ejected.

**Desired outcome**
--> Only Contact A with Case 1 is ejected. Contact A with Case 2 remains in the journey

Comment: were you able to figure out the desired outcome?

Comment: No, the customer was satisfied with a solution where the contact can enter the journey only once, which made it easier